# DAX distinctcount filtered column

Tags: ssas, dax

I need to display distinctcount of column values filtered by other column values. I'm already display this values, but I don't know how to count it
Here is my query:

`evaluate
    summarize(
        FILTER(
                Products
                ,not isblank(Produkty[Brand]) && Produkty[Company] = "blabla"
        )
        ,Produkty[Brand]
    )`

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if I got your field names correct, but this should do what you need.

```
Count of BlaBla Brands:=
calculate(
       countrows(distinct(Products[Brand])), 
       Filter('Products', Products[Company] = "blabla" && not(ISBLANK(Products[Brand])))
)
```